# Given the distribution of $X$ and $Y=-2\theta \ln X$. How is $Y$ distributed?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, proof-verification

The pdf of $X$ is $f(x) = \theta x^{\theta-1},\enspace 0<x<1, \enspace 0<\theta<\infty.$ Let $Y=-2\theta \ln X.$ How is $Y$ distributed?

My work:
$$
\begin{align*}
F(Y) = P(Y \leq y)
&= P(-2\theta \ln X\le y) \\
&= P(X \le e^{\frac{y}{-2\theta}}) \\
&= \int_{0}^{\frac{y}{-2\theta}}\theta x^{\theta-1}dx
\end{align*}
$$
and so
$$f(y)= \left(\frac{y}{-2\theta}\right)^{\theta}, \; -\infty <y<0 \quad \text{($0$ otherwise).}$$
Thus $Y$ is Exponentially Distributed with mean 2.

Is this ok?

Comment: Notice that if $y$ is positive then $f(y)= (\frac{y}{-2\theta})^{\theta}$ is negative for odd $\theta$. This will not work as a probability distribution.

Comment: fixed, how do the other steps look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be more careful:  The support of $X$ is $(0,1)$; consequently, $-\infty < \log X < 0$, and $\infty > -2\theta \log X > 0$.  So the transformation is **order-reversing** (larger values of $X$ give smaller values of $Y$), and you need to take this into account:  $$\begin{align*} \Pr[Y \le y] &= \Pr[0 < Y \le y] = \Pr[0 < -2\theta \log X \le y] = \Pr[\infty > X \ge e^{-y/(2\theta)}] \\ &= \Pr[1 > X \ge e^{-y/(2\theta)}]. \end{align*}$$  Therefore, $$F_Y(y) = \int_{x=\exp(-y/(2\theta))}^1 f_X(x) \, dx.$$

Alternatively, we can use the formula $$f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y)) \left| \frac{dg^{-1}}{dy} \right|,$$ where $Y = g(X) = -2 \theta \log X$, since $g$ is a monotone function.  Both methods yield the same result.

Comment: Good catch with the order reverse. Sorry if this is a silly question, but is the $0<Y \le  y$ part always true, but not always stated because it's taken to be obvious? Also, when you isolated X, why did the $0$ turn into $\infty$ and not $1$ immediately? Also is $Pr[Y \le y]$ equivalent to $F_Y(y)$ ?

Comment: $\Pr[Y \le y] = \Pr[0 < Y \le y]$ only if we know that the support of $Y$ is positive, and we know this because of how $Y$ relates to $X$, as described in the first sentence.  If $0 < X < 1$, then $0 < Y < \infty$.

Comment: When I isolated $X$, I solved the inequality $0 < -2\theta \log X \le y$ for $X$ by inverting the function:  this gives $e^{-0/(2\theta)} > X > e^{-y/(2\theta)}$ without presupposing any knowledge of $\theta$ (in particular, $\theta = 0$ makes the LHS indeterminate).  But since $0 < \theta < \infty$, the LHS does in fact become $1$.  Strictly speaking, we can proceed to the final step without really needing to write $\infty > X > \ldots$.

Comment: Yes, $\Pr[Y \le y] = F_Y(y)$, by definition of the cumulative distribution function.

Comment: At what point are you able to determine how $Y$ is distributed? Is it after taking the integral and examining the pdf of $Y$?

Comment: Once you obtain the CDF or PDF of $Y$, then it should be clear how $Y$ is distributed.